# How to parse from xml to json in xquery

Tags: xml, xquery

i have an xml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<groups>
  <group name="group1" location="city1">Group1</group>
  <group name="group2" location="city2">Group2</group>
</groups>
```

and i would like to parse it to a json string which has an output something like:

```
{
  "groups": [
    {
      "name": "group1",
      "location": "city1"
    },
    {
      "name": "group2",
      "location": "city2"
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried in my xql script the xml-to-json function with `fn:xml-to-json(/xml)` but did not success due to an exception: `FOJS0006  xml-to-json: element found in wrong namespace:`
Could anyone give me a hint how can i parse the xml correctly to json? Thank you in advanced!

i tried to google and some suggestion but didn't success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XQuery 3.1 doesn't have a function that converts arbitrary XML to JSON (the xml-to-json function only handles a limited XML vocabulary - read the spec!).

You need to do it by hand, for example

```
map{"groups": array{
    for $gp in groups/group 
    return map{"name": $gp/@name,
               "location": $gp/@location}
  }
}
```

And then to turn the tree of maps and arrays into lexical JSON, use the `serialize()` function with the JSON serialization method. You can also of course generate the lexical JSON "by hand" but getting the escaping and indentation right is tricky.